# How to solve summation convention

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I do not know where to begin and what I should be looking for with these three exercises.

I am looking for a partial solve with advice in solving the given equations; that involve particular subjects and questions I should have in mind.

1. if $Y_i = b_{ij}x_j$ and $Z_i = a_{ij}y_{j}$, show that $Z_i = c_{ij}x_j$, where $C_{ij} = a_{ik}b_{kj}$

and

2. If $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ and $b_{ij} = -b_{ji}$ show that $a_{ij}b_{ij}=0$

and

3. We define the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$ as follows: $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i = j$; and $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i$ not-equal-to $j$. Show that $a_{ij}\delta_{jk} = a_{ik} = \delta_{ij}a_{jk}$, where $i$, $j$, and $k$ take on the values $1, 2, ...,n.$

(Taken from: Mathematical methods in physics and engineers, Dettman - 2nd edition)

Comment: Is the sums finite? Or does it use infinite sums, and thus, some sense of convergence as well?

Comment: I believe it is finite

Comment: Are $Y_i$ and $y_i$ supposed to be the same?

Comment: No, that is why its $Y_i$ and $y_j$